# how to make a fadein animation effect on imageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m pulling an image from an url and showing it in an imageview.what i want is an fadein animation effect when the image gets loaded from the url.i m using a background threading below is the code..

```
    NSOperationQueue *theQueue=[[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init]autorelease];

    NSInvocationOperation *theOp=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImage) object:nil]; 

    [theQueue addOperation:theOp];  
}

-(void)loadImage
{

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSString *imagefile = [image  objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:imagefile];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
    UIImage *ui=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    NSLog(@"awesome:%@",ui);
    [ui beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    bigbanner.image=ui;
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [pool release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you say is absolutely correct and thats the way to do it. I wrote this method & always use this to Fade in my image. I deal with CALayer for this. You need to import Quartz framework for this.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

...

- (void)fadeInLayer:(CALayer *)l
{
    CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimate   = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeInAnimate.duration            = 0.5;
    fadeInAnimate.repeatCount         = 1;
    fadeInAnimate.autoreverses        = NO;
    fadeInAnimate.fromValue           = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    fadeInAnimate.toValue             = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    fadeInAnimate.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    [l addAnimation:fadeInAnimate forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
    return;
}
```

Usage: If you are using this from your current file, then -

```
    [self fadeInLayer:imageView.layer];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: is there a function call required to call this method

Comment: i tried adding the function call on above code..i m getting a warning ..coz bascicall its a thread...cud u help me out

Comment: post some code of how you are using it. Without that it gets difficult... But one advise is UI elements should always be updated on the main thread & not from background threads...

Comment: @srikar..thanks man your above code totally worked...i m able to get fade in animation effect of the image view from url..but before fading in i m having a small stutter and then then fade is taking into effect..any idea

Comment: sorry my bad..its working fine totally..used multithreading to call the above funciton...

Answer (score 1):

No need for autorelease pools if you use NSBlockOperation.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"]];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    self.bigbanner = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    self.bigbanner.alpha=0.;
}];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                     animations:^{ bigbanner.alpha = 1.0; }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
}];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

Maybe it should dispatch_async on the main thread to update the image, but works anyway. This won't do anything unless you have previously connected the UIImageView from your nib to an ivar on your class (ShiShi's answer explains how).

Comment: i m not getting the fade in transition...it remains the same..the bigbanner over there is an imageview that is in the nib file

Comment: dude thanks for your effort i used Srikar example...if i m to use NSBlockOperation will it increase my performance of loading image from the url? coz it takes takes time to load on imageview..is there any other better solution of loading image from an url

Comment: No it won´t. It´s slow and I don´t know exactly why.

Answer (score 1):

Editing my answer as I need some screenshot:

open your Interface builder , do want I did even with an empty image (it will be the place holder for the image you are about to update from the web later)

[image]

[image]

later just do this

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.75];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    theImage.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

Simple as that.

Comment: i m using an imageview in nib ..how to add this in the above code

Comment: change mySubView.alpha = 0.0; to self.view, u don't need to top part just the function removeTheView - OR even better use IB to add the mySubView to your nib

Comment: cud u clean up the code..i d be so greatful..i dont no where exactly i got to implement